# Simple blogging software (WP replacement)

Tags: wordpress, cms, looking-for-a-script, software, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question, but I think it's certainly better than at stackoverflow.com.

I'm planning to redesign my website and looking for a WordPress replacement for my blog. My requirements are:

- simple (I won't do a large, complicated website) and lucid
- well coded (OOP), extensions, templates, active development (not 3 years old)
- nice but temperate text editor (+images, links), tags and categories, page break
- easy integration with Flickr, Picasa and social networks
- technology: PHP and MySQL, not cloud service (like Posterous or Tumblr)

Could you recommend me some blogging software which would meet these criteria?

Comment: Hi, I tried to find something there, but found just too simple, not enough powerful solutions. Could you please move it? I hope someone will give me some suggestions.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why WordPress *isn't* simple enough for you, whatever that means? Realistically speaking, as far as the currently-active projects, it's pretty lightweight, not counting others that are more aggressively minimalist and therefore won't have all the plugins, integrations and such that you simultaneously want.

Comment: I'm just tired of it, that's all. And you need many plugins to get required functions. Meanwhile I found Habari (http://habariproject.org/en/), which might be something I'm looking for. What do you think about this one?

Comment: And could you list some of the others? They might be enough good for me...

Comment: Well coded doesn't necessarily mean object oriented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FlatPress](http://flatpress.org/home/) meets most of your requirements, in my experience.  I've been using it for a private blog for about a year and a half.  Point-by-point:

- It was simple to install and reasonably simple to install a theme.
- Development seems active (latest update was June 2011 as I type this).
- I've not really looked at the code, and don't know PHP that well anyway, so don't feel qualified to address whether it is well-coded.
- I find the editor easy to use and (think) it has everything asked for.
- I can't address its integration with social networks (like I said, I'm using it privately).
- It runs on PHP.  No database is used, the blog entries are saved as flat files, but since you say you're doing a small site, I wouldn't expect this to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you think one of the many available blogs is too heavyweight, have you considered using a Wiki instead?  I'm using the [Lion Wiki](http://lionwiki.0o.cz/index.php?page=Main%20page) which has practically no configuration and is very versatile. It also allows commenting as an option.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend Drupal. Using the core system plus selected modules you should be able to build a site that meets your specification

Comment: Well this is exactly the thing I'd like not to do. A pre-made package would be far better.

Comment: ...never mind that the request is for something *smaller/simpler* than WordPress. Which Drupal is...not.

Comment: Depends what was meant by simple. I assumed it meant simple for the visitor to the sites.

Drupal is as simple to set up as any package. Just follow the installation guide or use a hosting package that allows you to automatically install it from the control panel.

Being simple to use (for the site visitor) is not the same thing. Drupal allows you to create well structure, simple to navigate sites.

If WordPress isn't simple to set up/manage, then maybe someone can recommend a hosted service where someone else can do the installation/coding

Comment: Ok, that's my fault I didn't explain the "simple" better. It is meant not for installation nor for visitor, but overall for me to maintain and use it. I just don't need large CMS...